# Hive query to get count from previous day

Tags: sql, hive, hiveql

Table A
[image: Name City Year Month Day ABC Mumbai 2022 05 31 ABC Mumbai 2022 06 01 ABC Mumbai 2022 06 02 ABC Mumbai 2022 06 03 ABC Mumbai 2022 06 04]

Year(String), Month(String), and Day(String) are partition columns.

I want to get the count for the previous day.

Note - here no Date formate like 2022-06-01 in any columns

I tried the below query.

Select count(*) FROM Table A where Day='03' and Month='06' and Year='2022' GROUP BY city;

But I don't want to hard-coded value.

Answer (score 0):

I think I got the solution -

select count(*) from Table A where cast(concat_ws('-',year,month,day) as date)=date_sub(current_date, 1);

this is giving me the correct results.